# reloading page makes variable undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

i have a deckbuilder, a decklist component that shows the list of decks, and when i click on a deck the proper deck-details component is loaded using the deck's id with routing. This is the deck-details part where i use route.

```
 ngOnInit(){
 this.decks = this.deckService.getDecks(); // this just returns the array of decks
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params["id"];
      console.log(this.id);
      this.deck = this.decks.find((deck) => deck.id === this.id);
      console.log("deck-detail deck", this.deck);
}
```

and this is the app-routing.module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CardListComponent },
  { path: 'decks', component: DeckListComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id/:deckName', component: DeckDetailsComponent }
  ] },
  { path: 'createDeck', component: CreateDeckComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

so the url become something like this when i click on a deck: localhost:4200/decks/id/deckName.
If page is reloaded when the url is like this, deck-detail component is not reloaded with the page, and i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'deckName' of undefined
    at DeckDetailsComponent_Template
```

What i'm doing wrong? there is a component lifecycle problem? how can i avoid decks to be undefined when i reload the page?

Comment: what is `console.log(this.id);` during reload

Comment: the correct id is printed

Comment: you need to use    `this.routes.params.subscribe()` for reading values of id and deckName

Comment: i'm already using it in the deck-details component

Comment: @Syertim can you show your `DeckService`, are you getting your decks async?

Comment: can you create stackblitz of your demo?

Comment: You should show the code for DeckDetailsComponent

Comment: i'm getting the decks from a json with firebase

Comment: You are probably using `deck.deckName` in your deckDetailsComponent, before `deck` is assigned. Try using `*ngIf="deck"` to ensure the variable is set before trying to access its properties

Comment: i already tried to put this condition but when i do that and i click on a deck i have a similar behaviour as before (if i reload the page i don't see an "empty" deck-details because of the condition but when i click on a deck after reloading the page no deck-detail is never shown) and i have another error similar to the one before ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'deckClass' of undefined
    at deck-details.component.ts:56
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>) ```

Answer (score 0):

this is the whole deck-details component

```
import { Card } from "./../../card/card.model";
import { Deck } from "./../../deck/deck.model";
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DeckService } from "src/app/deck/deck.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { DataStorageService } from "src/app/shared/data-storage.service";
import { CardService } from "src/app/card/card.service";
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-deck-details",
  templateUrl: "./deck-details.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./deck-details.component.scss"],
})
export class DeckDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  //@Input() deck: Deck;
  paramsSubscription: Subscription;
  id: number;
  decks: Deck[];
  deck: Deck;
  cards: Card[];
  selectedClassCards: Card[];
  classes = [
    "Priest",
    "Mage",
    "Shaman",
    "Rogue",
    "Warrior",
    "Warlock",
    "Druid",
    "Paladin",
  ];
  addCardForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private deckService: DeckService,
    private cardService: CardService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataStorageService: DataStorageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addCardForm = new FormGroup({
      deckCards: new FormControl(),
    });
    this.cards = this.cardService.getCards();
    this.decks = this.deckService.getDecks();
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params["id"];

      this.deck = this.decks.find((deck) => deck.id === this.id);
      console.log("deck-detail deck", this.deck);
      this.selectedClassCards = this.cards.filter(
        (card) => card.hero === this.deck.deckClass || card.hero === "Neutral"
      );
    });
  }

  onDeleteCard(i) {
    this.deckService.deleteCard(this.deck, this.deck.deckCards[i]);
    //this.deckService.cardsChanged.next(this.deck.deckCards.slice());
    console.log(this.deck);
  }
  onAddCard() {
    this.deckService.addCard(this.deck, this.addCardForm.value.deckCards);
    console.log(this.deck);
  }

  onCardsEdit() {
    this.dataStorageService.storeCards(
      this.decks.indexOf(this.deck),
      this.deck.deckCards
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.paramsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and this is the DeckService

```
import { DataStorageService } from './../shared/data-storage.service';
import { Deck } from './deck.model';
import { Card } from '../card/card.model';
import {EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DeckService {
  deckSelected = new EventEmitter<Deck>();
  decksChanged = new Subject<Deck[]>();
  cardsChanged = new Subject<Card[]>();

  decks: Deck[] = [];
  remainingDecks: Deck[];


  constructor(/* private http: HttpClient, */ /* private dataStorageService: DataStorageService */) {}

  setDecks(decks: Deck[]) {
    this.decks = decks;
    this.decksChanged.next(this.decks.slice());
  }
  getDecks() {
    if (this.decks) {
      return this.decks.slice();
    }

}

  addCard(deck: Deck, card: Card){
    deck.deckCards.push(card);
}
  deleteCard(deck: Deck,  card: Card){
    deck.deckCards.splice( deck.deckCards.indexOf(card), 1);
  }

addNewDeck(deck: Deck){
  this.decks.push(deck);
  this.decksChanged.next(this.decks.slice());

};

deleteDeck(id: number) {
this.remainingDecks = this.decks.filter(
  deck => deck.id !== id
)
this.decks = this.remainingDecks;
this.decksChanged.next(this.decks.slice());
}

}
```

and this is where i store and fetch decks with fire base and httpClient

```
import { DeckService } from "./../deck/deck.service";
import { CardService } from "./../card/card.service";
import { Deck } from "./../deck/deck.model";
import { Card } from "./../card/card.model";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DataStorageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private deckService: DeckService) {}

  storeDecks() {
    const decks = this.deckService.getDecks();
    this.http
      .put("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks.json", decks)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("stored");
      });
  }
  fetchDecks() {
    return this.http
      .get<Deck[]>("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks.json")
      .subscribe((decks) => {
        decks
          ? this.deckService.setDecks(decks)
          : this.deckService.setDecks([]);
        console.log("fetching", decks);
      });
  }
  storeCards(i: number, cards: Card[]){
    this.http
    .put("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/" + i + "/deckCards.json", cards)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("cards stored");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: use behaviorsubject instead this `  decksChanged = new Subject<Deck[]>();`

Comment: could you explain better what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

for info this is the deck-detail component html template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="deck-details  " style="border:solid black">
      <!-- <img
        [src]="'../../assets/img/' + deck.deckClass + '.png'"
        alt="{{ deck.deckName }}"
        class="img-responsive"
        style="height: 200px;"
      /> -->

      <h1 contenteditable="true">{{ deck.deckName }} : {{ deck.deckClass }}</h1>
      <div *ngFor="let card of deck.deckCards; let i = index" >
        <span
      [ngClass]="{
        common: card.rarity == 'common',
        rare: card.rarity == 'rare',
        epic: card.rarity == 'epic',
        legendary: card.rarity == 'legendary'
      }"
    >
      {{ card.name }}
    </span>
    <h4 class="inlineh4">: {{ card.manaCost }} mana</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "onDeleteCard(i)" >delete</button>
       <!--  <img [src]="card.imagePath" alt="" style="height: 20px;" /> -->
      </div>
      <hr>
      <label for="deckCards">Add a Card</label>
      <form [formGroup]="addCardForm">
        <select formControlName="deckCards" id="deckCards" name="deckCards">
          <option *ngFor="let card of selectedClassCards" [ngValue]="card">
            {{ card.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
        <button (click)="onAddCard()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Add Card
        </button>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"(click) = "onCardsEdit()" >Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```